# Refreshing a datagrid without ObersvableCollection but with a property of my viewmodel

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemsource

I have a Datagrid. I want to refresh it when a event occurs.

So I have this :

```
 <DataGrid Name="matrix"  
Background="#3f4953" 
dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.Array2D="{Binding Path= Matrix,  
Mode=TwoWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
}"/>
```

I made this property in my ViewModel :

```
public string[,] Matrix { get; set; }
```

I made some maths to populate a 2d Array and I have this :

```
 Matrix = resultOfMyMaths;
```

I have this in my Xaml too :

```
  <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource vm}" />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

How can i Refresh my Datagrid now ?

For information : I change the value of Matrix in my code, it works. But my gridView doesn't refreh. I just have to bind the new value of Matrix in my datagrid.

I can't use an observableCollection because it's a multidimentional Array. And I can't cast my array to ObservableCollection. I already tried.

Comment: I guess, u should define a ObservableCollection of Matrix.  So like ObservableCollection<Matrix>. Then use binding or define a custom Matrix class to get regarding properties

Comment: Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (your xaml is already looking for that event! `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`). Then once you want to update the property you would call OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string property = null). Ideally you would use an ICommand if you update through Button click, if not then just call OnPropertyChancged.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on ViewModel class and fire `PropertyChanged` event with sender set to `this` and event args to `new PropertyCahngedEventArgs("Matrix")` to refresh binding.

Further reading on MSDN about INotifyPropertyChanged: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8